# Selenium - can't get the correct XPath using Chrome inspect elements - @id="layers" vs @id="react-root" - Python

Tags: python, reactjs, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to get the correct XPATH for the username box for the Twitter login.

My (simplified) code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver_service = Service(executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER_PATH)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driver_service)
url = "https://twitter.com/login"
driver.get(url)
user_name_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[5]/label/div/div[2]')
user_name_box.click()
```

Then, for whatever reason, Selenium can't find the element, and when I searched for the solution, the correct XPATH is '//*[@id="layers"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[5]/label/div/div[2]/div/input'

I suspect with my limited knowledge that this has something to do with React and the fact that the Twitter login box layers on top... but how do I access the correct XPath? Is there any way to select the correct XPath using Chrome? Or another tool?

Thanks very much. This is my first post on StackOverflow so be gentle :)

I was expecting that I could grab the correct XPath and then of course got an error.  Googled the correct XPath, found it, but would like to know what's happening and how to grab the correct XPaths if elements are sitting in layers.

Comment: What element are you trying to access there? `//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[5]/label/div/div[2]` locator matches nothing there

Comment: Was trying to get the username box but when I try to inspect it in Chrome and get the Xpath that's what it returns..  for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

A manual procedure using [xml2xpath](https://github.com/mluis7/xml2xpath) can be used to show all possible XPath expressions from an HTML/XML source.
Saving the page source from the browser  or the **Outer Html** from dev console to a file and passing a starting XPath expression:

```
xml2xpath.sh -s '//*[@id="react-root"]' -l tmp.html
```

Result using Outer Html

```
XPath expressions found: 99 (51 unique elements, use -r to override)
//*[@id="react-root"]
//*[@id="react-root"]/div
//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div
//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div
... [redacted]
//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/label/div
//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/label/div/div
//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/label/div/div/div
//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/label/div/div/div/span
//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/label/div/div/div/input
//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/span
//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/span/span
//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/span/span/span
//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/main
//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/main/div
//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/main/div/div
```

Testing an specific XPath expression to be used in Selenium

```
xml2xpath.sh -s '//*[@id="react-root"]//input[@autocomplete="username"]' -l tmp.html
```

Result (meaning expression matched elements)

```
XPath expressions found: 1 (1 unique elements, use -r to override)
//*[@id="react-root"]//input[@autocomplete="username"]
```

[xml2xpath](https://github.com/mluis7/xml2xpath) it's a bash script wrapper around `xmllint` XML tool.

If `-a` option is passed, absolute XPaths are returned similar to browser does

```
/html/body/div
/html/body/div/@id
/html/body/div/@style
/html/body/div/div
/html/body/div/div/@class
/html/body/div/div/div
/html/body/div/div/div/@class
/html/body/div/div/div/style
/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/@aria-label
/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/@class
/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/@id
/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/@class
/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/@id
/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/svg
/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/svg/@viewbox
/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/svg/@aria-hidden
/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/svg/@class
/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/svg/g
/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/svg/g/path
/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/svg/g/path/@d
/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]
/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]
/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/form
/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/form/@action
/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/form/@method
/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div
/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/@class
/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div
/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div/@dir
/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div/@class
/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div/@style
/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div/span
/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div/span/@class
/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/br
/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/input[1]
/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/input[2]
/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/input[1]/@type
/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/input[1]/@name
/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/input[1]/@value
/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/input[2]/@type
/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/input[2]/@value
```

**NOTE**: if source is an HTML fragment, `/html/body` are added by `xmllint` on what seems to be a bug.